# on one Fragment it gets value on other in same way created Fragment gets null

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

Im using **JSON** files to store data and Im creating ListFragment which is populated by Listviews which gets that data. And I need to extract it or store it on **AddFragment**, **ViewFragment** and its being sorted by UUID and it works fine on **ViewFragment** just **AddFragment** gets null on cloud value. Any Ideas where should I look for problems or how to solve it?

**ViewFragment:** cloud = CloudLab.get(getActivity()).getCloud(dreamIds); returns right value.

```
    public class ViewFragment extends Fragment{

    public static final String EXTRA_DREAMEE_ID = "com.example.tadas.dreamcload1.dream_id";

    private Cloud cloud;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UUID dreamIds = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DREAMEE_ID);
        cloud = CloudLab.get(getActivity()).getCloud(dreamIds);


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view, parent, false);


        return v;
    }

    public static ViewFragment newInstance(UUID dreamIds) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DREAMEE_ID, dreamIds);

        ViewFragment fragment = new ViewFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
}
```

But in **AddFragment** dCloud = CloudLab.get(getActivity()).getCloud(dreamId); returns null.

```
    public class AddFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "CloadLab";
    public static final String EXTRA_DREAM_ID = "com.example.tadas.dreamcload1.dream_id";

    private Cloud dCloud;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        UUID dreamId = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_DREAM_ID);
        dCloud = CloudLab.get(getActivity()).getCloud(dreamId);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add,parent,false);

        return v;
    }

    public static AddFragment newInstance(UUID dreamId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_DREAM_ID, dreamId);

        AddFragment fragment = new AddFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return  fragment;
    }


}
```

CloudLab class

```
public class CloudLab {

private static final String TAG = "CloudLab";
private static final String FILENAME = "dre.json";

private ArrayList<Cloud> mClouds;
private DreamCloudSerializer mSerializer;


private static CloudLab sCloudLab;
private Context mAppContext;


public CloudLab(Context appContext) {
    mAppContext = appContext;
    mSerializer = new DreamCloudSerializer(mAppContext, FILENAME);

    try {
        mClouds = mSerializer.loadDre();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        mClouds = new ArrayList<Cloud>();
        Log.e(TAG, "Error loading: ", e);
    }

}


public static CloudLab get(Context c) {
    if (sCloudLab == null) {
        sCloudLab = new CloudLab(c.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sCloudLab;
}


public void addDre(Cloud c) {
    mClouds.add(c);
}

public void deleteDre(Cloud c) {
    mClouds.remove(c);
}

public boolean saveDre() {
    try {
        mSerializer.saveDre(mClouds);
        Log.d(TAG, "saved to file");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error saving: ", e);
        return false;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Cloud> getClouds() {
    return mClouds;
}


public Cloud getCloud(UUID id) {
    for (Cloud c : mClouds) {
        if (c.getId().equals(id))
            return c;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you point exactly where it returns null? Where are you calling newInstance() for both fragments?

Comment: dCloud = CloudLab.get(getActivity()).getCloud(dreamId); returns null in AddFragment onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Your fragments are not exactly the same. You have different dream ids and are expecting same result.

```
// your id in ViewFragment
public static final String EXTRA_DREAMEE_ID = "com.example.tadas.dreamcload1.dream_ids";

// your id in AddFragment
public static final String EXTRA_DREAM_ID = "com.example.tadas.dreamcload1.dream_id";

// strings for your dream id in each fragment is different
```

Both strings are different. If you expect same result, pass same id. Or make sure both these ids when passed - exist and have same content.

Comment: If put same String I still get null in ADDFragment

Comment: not possible. update your code in the question after making the strings same - which still returns null..

Comment: Updated, I changed just String value but not names. Maybe names should be same as well?

Comment: i noticed that but that doesn't break your code because you are passing the right name for each class. But you should refactor and fix that too.

Comment: when Im starting ADDFragment from another Fragment do I need to pass that EXTRA_DREAM_ID on starting ADDFragmet?